# Playframework Scala Evolutions change database name for test

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, playframework-evolutions

I have my database structure in this file

```
myproject/conf/evolutions/mydatabasename/1.sql
```

and I have this configuration for tests

```
implicit override def newAppForTest(td: TestData): FakeApplication = FakeApplication(
  additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "evolutionplugin" -> "enabled",
    "db.mydatabasename.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
    "db.mydatabasename.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL",
    "db.mydatabasename.logStatements" -> true,
    "db.mydatabasename.username" -> "root",
    "db.mydatabasename.password" -> "root",
    "logback.com.jolbox" ->  "ERROR"
  )
)
```

If I change the folder name 'mydatabasename' for 'default' and in the configuration file 'mydatabasename' for 'default' it works, but when I try to change the name, it does not. Is there a way to make this work?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Play Scala are you using?

Comment: @Mikesname I am using playframework 2.4, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the `evolutions` module enabled in your `build.sbt` library dependencies, otherwise everything evolution-related will silently fail.

Your configuration appears to be outdated for 2.4.x, and you need to change it like so, specifically enabling evolutions for your data source:

```
additionalConfiguration = Map(
  "play.evolutions.db.mydatabasename.enabled" -> true,
  "db.mydatabasename.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
  "db.mydatabasename.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL",
  "db.mydatabasename.logStatements" -> true,
  "logback.com.jolbox" ->  "ERROR"
)
```

See [Evolutions Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions#Evolutions-configuration) in the docs.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried and I tried different things, but I am getting this error now "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find database for default"